# Getting a number from web scraping

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
driver.get("https://ispot2.faturaiqos.pt")
html = driver.page_source
soup = bs(html, "html.parser")
abpos = soup.find("div", {"class":"featured card-12"})
print(abpos)
driver.quit()
```

From this html:

```
<div class="featured card-12">11</div>
```

But the return is always this:

```
<div class="featured card-12"></div>
```

The number "11" (is always changing) and never appears :(

Comment: From this html:
<div class="featured card-12">11</div>

Comment: Shouldn't you log in first?

Comment: I´m already logged :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to wait until value is set

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver.get("https://ispot2.faturaiqos.pt")
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.featured.card-12')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: element.text)
print(element.text)
```

Update. To get text values from several nodes:

```
driver.get("https://ispot2.faturaiqos.pt")
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.featured.card-12')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: all([element.text for element in elements]))
print([element.text for element in elements])
```

Comment: it WORKSSS!!!! i have more than one ('div.featured.card-12') how can i use a "findALL" function to get every number?